# Android clear sessionStorage and localStorage allApps

Tags: android, webview, local-storage

So heres my usecase,

I have a parent application which acts as a launcher for a set of other applications.
These applications are webview based applications.

My parent application is not a system application and due to some reasons i cant sign it as a system application.

Now in my parent application when i logout,i want to kill the applications,

which im able to do but due to the data stored in localstorage and how these applications are written **the session in the webview continues**.

What i want to do is kill the child apps and clear their localstorages / sessionStorages.

I know the argument about it not ethical or appropriate to clear stuff of applications that i dont own,but im looking for loopholes which allow me to clear the local storage and session storage across all webview based applications.

**Im targetting only api 19 mainly so im not looking at lolipop or above.**

I have tried

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();
```

it didnt work.

And as my application is not a system application i cant use Runtime scripts like "pm clear ..."

Any tips or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> im looking for loopholes which allow me to clear the local storage and session storage across all webview based applications

That should not be possible, for obvious security reasons.

However, you should not need this for "all webview based applications". You need this for the ones that you wrote, that are being launched by this launcher. In that case, use some form of IPC to tell them to clear their own local storage. For example, you could use an explicit broadcast to send the clear-storage signal to each of the other apps that need to be cleared.

Comment: The problem is i dont own these applications to modify their code , was hoping api 19 had some workaround or loophole that i could use.
Thanks anyways